# Why cant I take a value from the current state and use that inside of my useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Currently, an object for the logged in user is set to the current state, which from the doe below you can see i am bringing in from the authContext. I am trying to take the user.firstName value and set that to the author inside of the useState hook. When i run this inside of my application, I look in the database where Log object is stored but the author value is blank. I am very new to coding so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
import LogContext from "../context/logs/logContext";
import AuthContext from "../context/auth/authContext";

const AddLogModal = () => {
  const logContext = useContext(LogContext);
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { user } = authContext;

  const { addLog } = logContext;

  const [log, setLog] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    attention: "",
    author: user.firstName,
    date: new Date(),
  });

  const { title, description, attention, author } = log;

  const onChange = (e) => setLog({ ...log, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title === "" || description === "" || attention === "") {
      M.toast({ html: "Please enter a title and description.." });
    } else {
      setLog({ ...log, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    addLog(log);

    setLog({
      title: "",
      description: "",
      attention: "",
      author: user.firstName,
    });
  };

  return (
    <form id="add-log-modal" className="modal" style={modalStyle}>
      <div className="modal-content">
        <h4>Open New Issue</h4>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="title" value={title} onChange={onChange} />
            <label htmlFor="message" className="active">
              Log Title
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="input-field">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="description"
            value={description}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="message" className="active">
            Log Description
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="input-field">
          <input type="text" name="author" value={author} onChange={onChange} />
          <label htmlFor="message" className="active">
            Created By:
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field">
            <p>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="attention"
                  checked={attention === "Needs Attention"}
                  value="Needs Attention"
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <span>Needs Attention</span>
              </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="attention"
                  checked={attention === "Issue Resolved"}
                  value="Issue Resolved"
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <span>Issue Resolved</span>
              </label>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <a
          href="#!"
          onClick={onSubmit}
          className="modal-close waves-effect waves-light blue btn"
        >
          Enter
        </a>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const modalStyle = {
  width: "75%",
  height: "75%",
};

export default AddLogModal;
```

***AuthContext***

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AuthContext from "./authContext";
import setAuthToken from "../setAuthToken";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../Types";

const AuthState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: false,
    user: {},
    error: null,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  // Load User
  const loadUser = async () => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");

      dispatch({ type: USER_LOADED, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR });
    }
  };

  // Register User
  const register = async (formData) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/users", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });

      loadUser();
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL,
        payload: err.response.data.msg,
      });
    }
  };
  // Login User
  const login = async (formData) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/auth", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });

      loadUser();
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
        payload: err.response.data.msg,
      });
    }
  };
  // Logout
  const logout = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT,
    });
  };
  // Clear Errors
  const clearErrors = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: CLEAR_ERRORS,
    });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        token: state.token,
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        loading: state.loading,
        user: state.user,
        error: state.error,
        register,
        login,
        clearErrors,
        loadUser,
        logout,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthState;
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? With what you have given there is not enough information. There seems to be no api calls, and nothing to update a database.

Comment: sorry about that. Above I have added some code from my authContext file where i am getting the User object from. This is loaded whenever someone logs in. To make things easier, what I am trying to do is simply take the firstName value from the User object and set that as the "author" property in the useState hook in the originally posted code.

Answer (score 0):

**React Docs:**

[If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value. Here’s an example of a counter component that uses both forms of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

**React Example:**

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
```